# multiple images in imagepicker

Tags: iphone, image

I'm relatively new to XCode and I m building Photo Collage App ..

I don't understand how to allow the user to pick multiple images from the UIImagePickerControler to create their collages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImagePickerController only allows one image to be selected at a time.

You have to use something *else* for multiple images to be selected in one go.

For my own projects, I use [ELCImagePickerController](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/03/update-elcimagepickercontroller/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not select multiple images with `UIImagePickerControler`. But you can use [ELCImagePickerController](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use ALAssetsLibrary instead of UIImagePicker...

read ALAssetsLibrary class reference on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722